# Slow inserts on database due to primary key

Tags: java, mysql, performance

Got a MySQL database with a table consisting values based on zipcode and house number. Primary key therefore is chosen to be zipcode and house number as these are the fields to search for. The database contains approximately 10 million records.

One specific zipcode consists of ~100000 different house numbers and extremely slow on inserting (1 hour per 10000 records).

Programming language is Java and I'm using prepared statements in a batch of 10000 with autocommit on false.

The structure of the table is the following:

```
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| zipcode         | varchar(6)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| house_no        | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| sanddcode       | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| depot           | varchar(3)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| network_point   | varchar(6)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| region          | varchar(3)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| seq             | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| cluster_id      | varchar(1)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| strand_id       | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| strand_props_id | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| version_id      | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Anyone who knows a solution to this? Thanks!

Comment: Zicode and house number is likely not a good primary key in that case. The reason is that the primary key **is unique**. That means when zipcode and house number are the primary key, there can be only one house with each number in each zip code. Are you aware of that?

Comment: @Philipp, I think the OP has a composite key, i.e. a key made up of multiple fields. In this case I don't see how that is a problem? I would still recommend a surrogate key instead though.

Comment: @KingCronus It is definitely a problem because one ZIP contains more than one street.

Comment: Composite primary key is not a very good idea, anyway. Use a sequence number for that and think later about enforcing any uniqueness constraints.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - Wow...goes to show I need an extra coffee today, of course you are right! I was not considering that case, in the UK (where I am located) I think there is a different code per street.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik That depends on the country. In some countries the combination of postal code (or zip code) and house number is unique.

Comment: In my experience I wouldn't recommend anything over 100 for the batch size. In fact, speed usually starts to decrease around 50. Using huge transactions may also cause problems, especially if you are doing anything else concurrently.

Comment: @Arjan ... and in such a country a single ZIP code does not contain ~100,000 house numbers :) But out of curiosity, which country do you have in mind?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: That seems logical :) In the Netherlands and in the UK the combination of postal codes and house numbers is unique.

Comment: I'd say this is a bad design, because you shouldn't have to change your database just because a house is knocked down or a zip code redrawn.  I'd have a surrogate key as the primary key and give unique constraints where appropriate.  No composite primary key here.

Comment: @Arjan So there's (at least) one ZIP per street or do you actually have a group of streets that don't share house numbers?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik in the Netherlands most postal codes cover just part of a street. Some postal codes cover parts of different streets, then those parts do not share house numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not trying to load data from the GUI, i would recommend sql loader, which loads all data in pretty fast time.

https://metacpan.org/pod/SQL::Loader::MySQL

http://www.roseindia.net/sql/mysql-example/loader-tutorial.shtml

Comment: If its a first time load, then you can go with this approach, and let your application take over the database once the initial loading is complete. Accept if you find it helpful.

Comment: For reference: don't comment your own answer; *edit* it. Comments are considered a second-class citizen on StackOverflow, more of a necessary evil than a feature.

Answer (score 1):

When you need to insert a lot of rows, it's probably faster to first remove the keys, then insert all the data, and then re-create the keys. That way the database does not need to spend a lot of time updating those keys.